# Search Bar doesnt refresh list on backspace

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have this search bar function in my Xamarin forms app and it works perfectly fine when you start to type all the information but when you start to delete the words. The view doesnt refresh and it just clears all the information.

Here is the code for the search

```
private void SearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            SearchBar searchBar = (SearchBar)sender;
            noMowersFoundLabel.IsVisible = false;
            //Check if the user cleared the text bar, if so: reload list of mowers
            if (searchBar.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                _viewModel.IsBusy = true;
                return;
            }
            //Max 6 digits in a serial number
            if (searchBar.Text.Length < 6)
            {
                //compares substrings to add to the list while the user has not entered full serial number
                var sorted = new List<Mower>();
                foreach (var m in _viewModel.Items)
                {
                    if (m.MachineSerialNumber.Length > searchBar.Text.Length)
                    {
                        //var serialNum = m.MachineSerialNumber.Substring(0, Math.Min(searchBar.Text.Length, 6));
                        if (m.MachineSerialNumber.Contains(searchBar.Text))
                        {
                            sorted.Add(m);
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach(var m in sorted)
                {
                    if (!m.MachineSerialNumber.Contains(searchBar.Text))
                    {
                        sorted.Remove(m);
                    }
                }
                sorted.Sort((p1, p2) => (p1.MachineSerialNumber.CompareTo(p2.MachineSerialNumber)));
                if(sorted.Count != 0)
                {
                    _viewModel.Items.Clear();
                    foreach(var m in sorted)
                    {
                        _viewModel.Items.Add(m);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    _viewModel.Items.Clear();
                    noMowersFoundLabel.IsVisible = true;
                }
            }
            else //user has entered full serial number
            {
                Mower selectedItem = null;
                foreach (var m in _viewModel.Items)
                {
                    if(m.MachineSerialNumber == searchBar.Text)
                    {
                        selectedItem = m;
                    }
                }

                if(selectedItem != null)
                {
                    //We found the item
                    _viewModel.Items.Clear();
                    _viewModel.Items.Add(selectedItem);
                }
                else{
                    //No item found
                    _viewModel.Items.Clear();
                    noMowersFoundLabel.IsVisible = true;
                }
            }
```

I want the view to populate the information when you start to delete words

Comment: does the event fire on backspace?  If so then you need to debug your code to see why it isn't doing what you expect.

Comment: doesn't fire on backspace that the problem

Comment: To be sure: You put a breakpoint at start of that function? VS stops at breakpoint when user types a letter, but not when they press backspace?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is necessary to diffentiate the length of the input string.

I created a demo and achieved this function, you can refer to the following code:

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel 
{

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel() { 
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        Items.Add(new Item { Name="name1" , MachineSerialNumber="0001"});
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "name2", MachineSerialNumber = "0102" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "name3", MachineSerialNumber = "1203" });
        Items.Add(new Item { Name = "name4", MachineSerialNumber = "11204" });

    }

    public  List<Item> GetSearchResults(string queryString)
    {
        var normalizedQuery = queryString?.ToLower() ?? "";
        return Items.Where(f => f.MachineSerialNumber.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(normalizedQuery)).ToList();
    }
}
```

**Item.cs**

```
public class Item 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string MachineSerialNumber { get; set; } 
}
```

**TestPage1.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SearchBarDemos.TestPage1">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar"
                   HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   Placeholder="Search fruits..."
                   CancelButtonColor="Orange"
                   PlaceholderColor="Orange"
                   TextTransform="Lowercase"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                   TextChanged="searchBar_TextChanged"/>
            <Label Text="Type in the searchbox to filter results in realtime."
               HorizontalOptions="Fill"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <ListView x:Name="searchResults" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                  HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                  VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}"
                              Detail="{Binding MachineSerialNumber}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>

            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**TestPage1.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TestPage1 : ContentPage 
{

    MyViewModel _viewModel;
    public TestPage1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _viewModel = new MyViewModel();
        this.BindingContext = _viewModel;

    }

    private void searchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        searchResults.ItemsSource = _viewModel.GetSearchResults(e.NewTextValue);
    }
}
```

**Note:**

I added a function `GetSearchResults` into `MyViewModel.cs`

```
    public  List<Item> GetSearchResults(string queryString)
    {
        var normalizedQuery = queryString?.ToLower() ?? "";
        return Items.Where(f => f.MachineSerialNumber.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(normalizedQuery)).ToList();
    }
```

And once entering the input string, we can do as follows:

```
   private void searchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        searchResults.ItemsSource = _viewModel.GetSearchResults(e.NewTextValue);
    }
```